# regex: how can use \G With this replacement

Tags: .net, regex

I want to replace this:

```
Tata: 012345
Toto: 3421
Titi: 12345678
```

To

```
Tata: 01 23 45
Toto: 34 21
Titi: 12 34 56 78
```

I use:

(?!^)\G|\G\d{2}

But it dont match

Thanks

Edit: thanks but my question is about \G assertion..

Comment: Updated my answer, any questions drop a comment please, because your edit will not give us notifications whereas comments do. Of course you can edit the question but dropping the comment will give us notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the `\G` feature at all. If there are several consecutive digits, the regex engine will find them without to check if they are contiguous or not.

You can use this replacement:

```
Regex.Replace(txt, @"[0-9]{2}(?=[0-9])", "$0 ");
```

The lookahead is used to check if there is a digit after the 2 digits, this avoid to add a trailing space.

How to use the `\G` feature:

`\G` is an anchor that describes the start of the string position or the position at the end of the last match. If you want to use `\G` and avoid the start of the string, you must add a lookaround to exclude the start of the string ( `(?!^)\G` or `(?<!^)\G` ) *(you can put it after too, this is exactly the same since it is, as `\G`, a zero-width assertion.)*

`(?!^)\G` needs a precedent match to succeed. If I take your example, the entry point of this (successful) first match may be: `(?<=: [0-9]{2})`

Without this entry point, your pattern will ever fail if it can only start with `(?!^)\G` because you will never have a first match.

You obtain this pattern:

```
@"(?:(?<=: [0-9]{2})|(?!^)\G)[0-9]{1,2}"
```

that works with this replacement `" $0"`

For each line the first match will take the first alternative path and all consecutive matches will take the second path.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var subject = "Tata: 012345";
var result = Regex.Replace(subject,@"\d{2}","$0 ");
```

**Edit**: As to why your `\G` doesn't work?  `\G` Checks for Last match position, it should start next match over there. So initially there is no match it will check if there is any match can be done in index `0`, in this case no it can't. That's why it fails.

Am not sure what you mean by this pattern `(?!^)\G|\G\d{2}`. If your pattern was `\G\d{2}` and your subject has only numbers it will have worked.

Example:

```
var subject = "012345";
var result = Regex.Replace(subject,@"\G\d{2}","$0 ");
```

Will result in `01 23 45`

Answer (score 1):

to give you an example about `\G` assertion
look at this pattern `(^\w+:\s|\G)\d{2}`
it sorta works like so:

- `^\w+:\s` first find `^\w+:\s\d{2}`
- `|` then
- `\G` from last match find `\G\d{2}`
  [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xP1zK7)